# How to make (yes/no or 1-0) decisions with random forest?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

This is the data set from Kaggle's Titanic competition ([train](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar0y71vBm1oLeTNZl17c1l1bHrw) and [test](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar0y71vBm1oLeAGIr7o1s1BG5q4) csv files). Each file has features of passengers such as ID, sex, age, etc. The train file has a "survived" column with 0 and 1 values. The test file is missing the survived column as it has to be predicted. 
This is my simple code using random forest to give me a benchmark for the starter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import random
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

train=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train['Type']='Train' #Create a flag for Train and Test Data set
test['Type']='Test'
fullData = pd.concat([train,test],axis=0) #Combined both Train and Test Data set

ID_col = ['PassengerId']
target_col = ["Survived"]
cat_cols = ['Name','Ticket','Sex','Cabin','Embarked']
num_cols= ['Pclass','Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare']
other_col=['Type'] #Test and Train Data set identifier

num_cat_cols = num_cols+cat_cols # Combined numerical and Categorical variables
for var in num_cat_cols:
    if fullData[var].isnull().any()==True:
        fullData[var+'_NA']=fullData[var].isnull()*1 

#Impute numerical missing values with mean
fullData[num_cols] = fullData[num_cols].fillna(fullData[num_cols].mean(),inplace=True)
#Impute categorical missing values with -9999
fullData[cat_cols] = fullData[cat_cols].fillna(value = -9999)

#create label encoders for categorical features
for var in cat_cols:
 number = LabelEncoder()
 fullData[var] = number.fit_transform(fullData[var].astype('str'))

train=fullData[fullData['Type']=='Train']
test=fullData[fullData['Type']=='Test']

train['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(train)) <= .75
Train, Validate = train[train['is_train']==True], train[train['is_train']==False]

features=list(set(list(fullData.columns))-set(ID_col)-set(target_col)-set(other_col))

x_train = Train[list(features)].values
y_train = Train["Survived"].values
x_validate = Validate[list(features)].values
y_validate = Validate["Survived"].values
x_test=test[list(features)].values

Train[list(features)]

#*************************
from sklearn import tree

random.seed(100)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

status = rf.predict_proba(x_validate)
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_validate, status[:,1]) #metrics. added by me
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print(roc_auc)

final_status = rf.predict_proba(x_test)
test["Survived2"]=final_status[:,1]

test['my prediction']=np.where(test.Survived2 > 0.6, 1, 0)

test
```

As you can see, the final_status gives the probability of survival. I'm wondering how to get yes/no (1 or 0) answers from it. The easiest thing that I could think of was to say if probability is greater than 0.6 then the person survived and otherwise died ('my prediction' column) but once I submit the results, the predictions are not good at all.

I appreciate any insights. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with `test.csv` and `train.csv` so we can run the code?

Comment: Eric it's already uploaded. Please see the first line of my post. Just download them and the code is ready to run. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transforming your probability into binary output is the right way to go, but why did you choose > .6 and not > .5?

Also, if you are having bad results in that case, it is most likely because you did not do a proper job in data cleaning and feature extraction. For example, the title ("Mr", "Mrs",...) can give you indication on the gender, which is a super important feature to consider in your problem (I assume this is the titanic competition from kaggle).

Comment: Thanks. You're right it's from Kaggle; I've actually acknowledged that in the first line of my post. 
I tried .5, .6, .7 etc. but none of them were satisfactory. You're right that it's not a good model but like I've said in the post, it's supposed to provide just a quick benchmark for the starter.
With regard to transforming probability into binary output, are there any keywords that I can use to search and learn? like are there functions for that in Python or do I need to write an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use a line like:

```
out = rf.predict(x_test)
```

and that would be the 0/1 answers I was looking for.